# Specific type for Bibliography

Tags: tables, bibliographies

There is this specific type of bibliography I really want to do in TeX (picture below).

I don't have that many books in my thesis that I need some organizing tool like BibTeX, a mere reproduction would do the trick. Still, I'm not really sure how to do that efficiently.

I thought about making a table for year / title, but then the author in bold crosses the columns.

I thought about typing the author in bold, then having a table for his books, then another author - another table - but even if I do that I have the problem that long book titles get cut off, because I cannot naturally write over two lines in a table.

This would be possible with minipage, but before I start to do a `\textbf{Author}` then `\minipage` and then `\textbf{Author}` again I thought about asking you guys.

...also: how can I do this slightly bigger blank line after each section of books?

[image]

--

Comment: It would be appreciated if you could provide the foundation through a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv)...even if this just implies you supplying the community with a typed-out version of your image. It'll avoid use having to do that from scratch.

Comment: Note some institutions require a set style for submission. Even if yours does not, you will be expected to use the style which is standard for your subject or, if there is no such style, one of the standard styles. You should not invent your own or use a style normally applied only in other disciplines.  (Unless your institutional rules demand a set style regardless of your discipline's norms. But even places with potty regulations for formatting tend to recognise the importance of adhering to disciplinary conventions for citations and bibliography.)

Comment: Take a look at the `philosophy-modern` style of the [**biblatex-philosophy** bundle](http://texdoc.net/pkg/biblatex-philosophy) (§2.2 of the manual)

Comment: Thank you all for your feedback – I thought about including a MWE but in this stage of confusion all I could have posted would be a silly workaround that's not worth much.  And @cfr that's also a good point, I'm definitely going to check the standards.  Thank you all, `philosophy-modern` looks amazing!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could adapt the `philosophy-modern` style of the [**biblatex-philosophy** bundle](http://texdoc.net/pkg/biblatex-philosophy).

It has an option for printing author names in small-caps `scauthors` which defines a `\mkbibsc` formatting command. We can redefine the latter when it is applied to `\textbf` instead.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[sc,osf]{mathpazo}
\usepackage[style=philosophy-modern,scauthors=true]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\AtBeginBibliography{
\iftoggle{bbx:scauthorsbib}{%
  \renewrobustcmd{\mkbibsc}[1]{\textbf{#1}}}
{}}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

> [image: mwe]

Comment: Oh my goodness - this looks absolutely perfect! Thank you so much!