# Customizing bibliography: sorting papers by Author

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

I'd like to customize my biblatex bibliography. Instead of the standart format,

> **References**
>
> [1]  Paul Adrien Maurice Dirac. The  Principles  of  Quantum 
>   Mechanics. International series of monographs on physics. Clarendon
>   Press, 1981.
>
> [2]  Paul Adrien Maurice Dirac. Pride and Prejudice. Procceedings of
>   the Aristotelian Society. Clurandon Press, 1999.
>
> [3]  Albert Einstein. “Zur Elektrodynamik bewegter Korper. (German)
>   [On the electrodynamics of moving bodies]”. In: Annalen der Physik
>   322.10 (1905), pp. 891–921.
>
> [4]  Albert Einstein. “Nochmal was zur Elektrodynamik bewegter
>   Korper''. (German) [More on the electrodynamics of moving bodies]”.
>   In: Annalen der Physik 422.10 (1925), pp. 1891–1921.

I would like to have the format

> **Dirac, P. A. M.**
>
> 1981     The  Principles  of  Quantum  Mechanics. International series
>   of monographs on physics. Clarendon Press.
>
> 1999   Pride and Prejudice. Procceedings of the Aristotelian Society.
>   Clurandon Press.
>
> **Einstein, A.**
>
> 1905 Zur Elektrodynamik bewegter Korper. (German) [On the
>   electrodynamics of moving bodies]”. In: Annalen der Physik 322.10, pp.
>   891–921.
>
> 1920   Nochmal was zur Elektrodynamik bewegter Korper''. (German)
>   [More on the electrodynamics of moving bodies]”. In: Annalen der
>   Physik 422.10, pp. 1891–1921.

Is there a way straightforward way to do this?

Comment: You may be interested in the style `philosophy-modern` of the [`biblatex-philosophy`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-philosophy) bundle.

Comment: See for example https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/283815/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/416349/35864

Comment: Yes, perfect. That's exactly what I was looking for, thank you very much!!

Comment: If that is the case I suggest marking this post as duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/283815/35864, would be OK with that?

Comment: Yes, that's fine!. Thanks for your help again.

Comment: Very well, then, done! Glad I could help.